# tkinter and Pylance: argument of type tuple cannot be assigned to parameter "command" of type none

Tags: tkinter, vscode-extensions, tkinter-entry, pylance, tkinter-button

I use VS Code as my IDE and I have Pylance extension to help debugging the code.

Pylance keeps underlining `command=self.get_inputs` as error even thought the code runs just fine. Here is an example:

`self.button1 = ctk.CTkButton(self, text="Calculate", command=self.get_inputs) self.button1.grid(row=5, column=0, pady=10, padx=10, sticky="W")`

```py
def get_inputs(self):
    H1 = self.entry2.get()
    d1 = self.entry3.get()
    T = self.entry4.get()
    alpha1 = self.entry5.get()
    s = self.entry6.get()
    z = self.entry7.get()
    d2 = self.entry8.get()

    return H1, d1, T, alpha1, s, z, d2
```

Here is the full error:
[full error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFWzN.png)

I don't understand why this is happening. what can I do avoid getting this?

I don't know how I can avoid getting this type of error

Comment: Try adding type annotations to the method definition: `def get_inputs(self) -> None:` (this specifies that `get_inputs` has no `return` value, or more accurately, returns `None`)

Comment: get_inputs returns a bunch of variables, sorry I forgot to add that to the code, ill edit it now.

Comment: Ah! In that case, try annotating `def get_inputs(self) -> tuple[str, str, str, str, str, str, str]:`, or (perhaps less accurately, but less obnoxiously) `def get_inputs(self) -> tuple[str, ...]:`. I think what's happening here is that Pylance is mad about not having a return type annotation for this method.

Comment: Please don't post a picture of the error. Copy and paste the text into your question.

Comment: None of these fixed the issue :/

Comment: Does  this help? tuple[[str, str, str, str], [str, str, str]]